# Executing controllers methods from a library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, github, codeigniter-2

i have a question, i am developing a library for Codeigniter to create Job Queues with workers and delayed queue ([Codeigniter-JobQueue](http://github.com/marsanla/Codeigniter-jobQueue)). But i have a question...
... How can i perform or execute controller's methods inside this library? It will be awesome to know this.

The library is taking "controller, method, params" to transform after to "http://www.example.com/controller/method/params".

Thanks, and if you want to help me to develop, you are welcome. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use curl. If you however expect a return variable from controllers method, then C in your MVC is not designed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Curl is a way to go. Controllers should output content and not return a variable. If you are scheduling any job, the library should call the URL itself. You could use the cli mode of codeigniter.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html